# ImportErrorr triggered by pandocfilters installed by pip3

Tags: python3, pip, pandoc

## Goal

To get [pandocfilters](https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters) running with pip3.

## My Error

Here's my steps to reproduce the error.

1. Install pandocfilters through pip3: `pip3 install pandocfilters`.
2. Download the scripts `examples/caps.py` and `examples/plantuml.py` to `~/.pandoc/filters/`.  (Default user data location shown by `pandoc -v` is `~/.pandoc`.)
3. Append `3` to the first line of `plantuml.py`, so that it becomes `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.
4. Compile Markdown to PDF: `pandoc foo.md -o bar.pdf --filter plantuml.py`.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vin100/.pandoc/filters/plantuml.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Para, Image, get_filename4code, get_caption, get_extension
ImportError: No module named pandocfilters
pandoc: Error running filter /home/vin100/.pandoc/filters/plantuml.py
Filter returned error status 1
```

How can I get pandocfilter work with pip3?

## Technical details

[Line 14 of `plantuml.py`](https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters/blob/c6a1cee4fa99857dd1df8f2ad997d931ade39611/examples/plantuml.py#L14) shows

```py
from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Para, Image, get_filename4code, get_caption, get_extension
```

I've verified that I've really installed pandocfilters.

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep pandocfilters
pandocfilters==1.4.2
```

The installed location is `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

```
$ pip3 show pandocfilters
Name: pandocfilters
Version: 1.4.2
Summary: Utilities for writing pandoc filters in python
Home-page: http://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters
Author: John MacFarlane
Author-email: fiddlosopher@gmail.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/vin100/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
```

Here's the output of `ls` at the above `Location`.

```
$ pip3 show pandocfilters | grep home | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs ls -al
total 160
drwx------ 28 vin100 vin100  4096 Jul  3 10:00 .
drwx------  3 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 awscli
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 awscli-1.16.169.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  6 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 botocore
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 botocore-1.12.159.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 colorama
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 colorama-0.3.9.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  6 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 dateutil
drwxr-xr-x  9 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 docutils
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 docutils-0.14.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 jmespath
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 jmespath-0.9.4.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Aug  3 22:44 pandocfilters-1.4.2.dist-info
-rw-r--r--  1 vin100 vin100  8271 Aug  3 22:44 pandocfilters.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jul  3 10:00 pandoc_mermaid_filter-0.1.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--  1 vin100 vin100  1154 Jul  3 09:59 pandoc_mermaid_filter.py
drwxr-xr-x  6 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 pyasn1
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 pyasn1-0.4.5.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jul  3 10:00 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 python_dateutil-2.8.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 PyYAML-3.13.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 rsa
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 rsa-3.4.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 s3transfer
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 s3transfer-0.2.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 six-1.12.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--  1 vin100 vin100 32452 Jun  2  2019 six.py
drwxr-xr-x  6 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 urllib3
drwxr-xr-x  2 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 urllib3-1.25.3.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 vin100 vin100  4096 Jun  2  2019 yaml
```

pandocfilter is a single-file module.  From the relevant [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), line 14 in `plantuml.py` looks good to me.  I understand this as `from <script_file_name> import <script_method_name>`.

I don't write much Python code, and my `$PYTHONPATH` is empty.

---

Edit in response to comments, thanks to [byzanz-gui](https://github.com/rhcarvalho/byzanz-gui).

[image: Python3 response]
[image]

Comment: What happens when you open a command, type `python` and then `import pandocfilters`? I'm not sure the `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is used when pandoc calls python.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke `ImportError: No module named pandocfilters`, b/c my `python` is 2.7.  Ubuntu uses `python3` by default for Python 3.  When I use `python3` instead, I don't see this error.

Comment: And when you do `python3` and then `import pandocfilters` it does work?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Excuse me for delay.  Yes, I've included a GIF recorded using byzanz-gui for reference.

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing here, so not sure this helps, but could you replace `#!/usr/bin/env python3` with the full path to your `python3` binary in the `plantuml.py` file? You can get the full path with `type python3`. So it will become something like `#!/usr/bin/path/to/python3`

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke No worries.  PlantUML has an online server to generate UML diagrams in PNG format, which would be enough for my HW.  From this, I see a bigger question: my understanding of Python's `import` and the setup of Python 3 modules through `pip3` on *nix.  I'm glad that you've read and offered help.  Return to your question: I've tried but I got the same results.  Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111401/discussion-between-saaru-lindestokke-and-gnusupporter-8964-).